# I have two multiselect dropdowns, the second one is dependent on the first one

Tags: arrays, angular, javascript-objects, multi-select

If the selected location is Central Office, list all Office and Division If the selected location is Office which region is not tagged as Central Office, list all Division and Section, and if all the Central office non-central offices are selected, then all the Division, Office and Section should be populated in the second multi-select dropdown. The comparison is based on type property in both of them.

**Here's my location array:**

```
[
    {
        "label": "test(Central Office)",
        "value": "0F2B0AA8E6414D3F9EADCD3E9FB9E217",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "test(Central Office)",
        "value": "BDCE90479A9E48A99610D32B2FE47CAF",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 4",
        "value": "0F86B741642C4C2386EAB57D468214E6",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 2",
        "value": "1843B97B86DD4F1A9BC453D270EE4F68",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 6",
        "value": "611FBE0D7A2F4400A8BEF92DF4C5BE09",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 5",
        "value": "E5AB483B32AC43E99A0A400EB05C273E",
        "type": 0
    }
]
```

**Here's my organizational array:**

```
[
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 3(Office)",
        "value": "0F2B0AA8E6414D3F9EADCD3E9FB9E217",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 4(Office)",
        "value": "0F86B741642C4C2386EAB57D468214E6",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 2(Office)",
        "value": "1843B97B86DD4F1A9BC453D270EE4F68",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 6(Office)",
        "value": "611FBE0D7A2F4400A8BEF92DF4C5BE09",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 1(Office)",
        "value": "BDCE90479A9E48A99610D32B2FE47CAF",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST OFFICE 5(Office)",
        "value": "E5AB483B32AC43E99A0A400EB05C273E",
        "type": 0
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST DIVISION3(Division)",
        "value": "17425F2B5F3E4839A1803FE5339CBE15",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST DIVISION 2(Division)",
        "value": "4AEE41A1D3B0480B843559EC42518614",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST DIVISION 1(Division)",
        "value": "93A546AE75E841F696C601C7714FB1A1",
        "type": 1
    },
    {
        "label": "TEST SECTION 1(Section)",
        "value": "0C7B0E3F51D44C57B8E5D42EF1FD6345",
        "type": 2
    }
]
```

**And after selecting the locational, they are stored in an array like this:**

```
[
    "0F2B0AA8E6414D3F9EADCD3E9FB9E217",
    "BDCE90479A9E48A99610D32B2FE47CAF",
    "0F86B741642C4C2386EAB57D468214E6",
    "1843B97B86DD4F1A9BC453D270EE4F68",
    "611FBE0D7A2F4400A8BEF92DF4C5BE09",
    "E5AB483B32AC43E99A0A400EB05C273E"
]
```

**Here's my typescript code:**

```
filterOrganizationalUnits() {
    this.availableOrganizationalUnits = [];

    const filteredLocations = this.locations.filter((location: any) => {
      return (
        this.dataLocationText.includes(location.Text) || location.Type === 1
      );
    });

    console.log('location', location);

    filteredLocations.forEach((location: any) => {
      const filteredUnits = this.organizational.filter((unit: any) => {
        if (location.Type === 1 && unit.Type === 0) {
          // If selected location is Central Office, list all Offices
          return true;
        } else if (
          location.Type === 0 &&
          ((unit.Type === 1 &&
            !this.dataOrgUnitText.find(
              (parent: any) =>
                parent.Type === 0 &&
                parent.Value === location.Value &&
                parent.Text === unit.Value
            )) ||
            unit.Type === 2)
        ) {
          // If selected location is Office which region is not tagged as Central Office, list Division and Section
          return unit.Type === 1 || unit.Type === 2;
        }
        return false;
      });

      this.availableOrganizationalUnits.push(...filteredUnits);
    });

    this.new = this.availableOrganizationalUnits.map((item: any) => ({
      label:
        item.Type === 0
          ? item.Value + ' (Office)'
          : item.Type === 1
          ? item.Value + ' (Division)'
          : item.Value + ' (Section)',
      value: item.Text,
      type: item.Type,
    }));

    // Uncomment the console.log statements for debugging
    console.log('new', this.new);
    // console.log('availableOrganizationalUnits', this.availableOrganizationalUnits);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you're trying to implement a filtering logic for two multiselect dropdowns based on the selected location and organizational units.

```
filterOrganizationalUnits() {
  this.availableOrganizationalUnits = [];

  const filteredLocations = this.locations.filter((location) => {
    return this.selectedLocations.includes(location.value) || location.type === 1;
  });

  filteredLocations.forEach((location) => {
    const filteredUnits = this.organizational.filter((unit) => {
      if (location.type === 1 && unit.type === 0) {
        // If selected location is Central Office, list all Offices and Divisions
        return true;
      } else if (
        location.type === 0 &&
        ((unit.type === 1 &&
          !this.selectedLocations.some((selectedLocation) =>
            this.organizational.some((parent) =>
              parent.type === 0 &&
              parent.value === selectedLocation &&
              parent.label === unit.label
            )
          )) ||
          unit.type === 2)
      ) {
        // If selected location is Office and its region is not tagged as Central Office, list Divisions and Sections
        return unit.type === 1 || unit.type === 2;
      }
      return false;
    });

    this.availableOrganizationalUnits.push(...filteredUnits);
  });

  this.new = this.availableOrganizationalUnits.map((item) => ({
    label:
      item.type === 0
        ? item.label + ' (Office)'
        : item.type === 1
        ? item.label + ' (Division)'
        : item.label + ' (Section)',
    value: item.value,
    type: item.type,
  }));

  // Uncomment the console.log statements for debugging
  console.log('new', this.new);
  // console.log('availableOrganizationalUnits', this.availableOrganizationalUnits);
}
```

replace the variable names (this.selectedLocations, this.locations, this.organizational, etc.) in the code with the actual variable names you are using in your application.

hope it helpful..